Why is my tshark command exporting blank fields?

This is a packet capture (aka pcap) file from a Bittorrent session, and I’m interested in the bitfield message in frame 5 (highlighted above). I want to extract bitfields from a lot of pcap files and this one is my test. I want to use a command like this:
tshark -r 3841184718_50.35.114.84.pcap -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f -e "bittorrent.msg.bitfield" -e "ip.src" -e “ip.dst"

…but the output is:
bittorrent.msg.bitfield,ip.src,ip.dst
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,

(27 more rows of ,,)

tshark is clearly reading the file, because it outputs 32 rows and there are 32 frames in the pcap file. But why are all the fields I want coming out blank?

You're asking tshark to display bittorrent fields from packets that are not bittorrent packets, hence the empty fields.  Try adding a display filter to limit the output to only bittorrent-relevant packets, e.g., -Y "bittorrent".  You might also want to include the -2 option, which is generally a good idea especially where reassembly is needed.

Thanks for the suggestion- I'll try this
